# Как правильно модифицировать класс во время его загрузки? JNI/Java

Tags: java, jni

Вопрос таков. Есть файл `Lib.jar` и есть `JNILib.dll`.

Необходимо, что бы после подгрузки `Lib.jar` загружалась `JNILib.dll` и изменяла класс `a.test.Class` из `Lib.jar` до того, как его начала использовать JVM.

Как это выполнить?
Я знаю, как загрузить dll, я имею ввиду, какие функции из JNI мне необходимо использовать?

P.S. Агенты не подойдут, необходима JNI.

Comment: Да, что именно не понятно?

Comment: @AGrief, можете пояснить этот момент: _изменяла класс a.test.Class из Lib.jar до того, как его начала использовать JVM_

Comment: Вы можете написать classloader, который загрузит `Lib.jar` и в процессе загрузки произведет трансформацию, логика трансформации при этом будет вынесена в `JNILib.dll`. *(если я правильно понял задачу)*